# Movie about a robot restoring the human population with a machine that can create human babies

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The entirety of humanity has become extinct, but there is a base with a machine that can create human babies. The machine creates a baby and a robot starts to take care of it. The baby grows up into a teenage girl. Soon after that, the machine starts to create another baby, which will be the teenager's brother.

I think later the teenager wants to leave the base, but the robot won't let her, and they later get into conflict.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: I think I watched it when I was 10, and the movie seemed new.

Comment: Similar plot, but two "sisters" on a new planet (colonialisation project), who later meet other humans (survivers from stranded spaceship) in german language: [KI-mom](https://www.swr.de/swr2/hoerspiel/podcast-ki-mom-100.html)

Comment: Oh, maybe I should watch that, is it good?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is this ***[I Am Mother](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6292852/)*** (2019)...?

After an unspecified "extinction event," automated systems come online in a high-tech bunker and assemble a vaguely humanoid robot. The robot then retrieves a human embryo from cold storage and places it in an artificial womb, where it rapidly grows into a baby girl. The girl is subsequently reared and educated by the robot, which speaks to her with a woman's voice, and fosters a mother/daughter relationship with her. In fact, the girl only knows the robot as 'Mother' and the only name given to the girl is 'Daughter.'

> [image: Image of Mother and Daughter, from "I Am Mother" (2019).]
>
> <sub>*I Am Mother* (2019)</sub>

Much later in the film, when Daughter is in her teens, Mother asks her to choose another embryo from the thousands remaining in cold storage, so that it can be grown into another member of their family. The embryo chosen is grown into a baby boy, referred to as 'Brother.'

> [image: Image of Daughter and Brother, from "I Am Mother" (2019).]
>
> <sub>*I Am Mother* (2019)</sub>

Daughter becomes increasingly curious about the state of the world outside the bunker and whether it's safe to go out or not, but Mother insists that it isn't, leading to growing tensions between the two.

Comment: Yes, It was this one, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Could it be a TV series: [*The Outer Limits* S02E02 "Resurrection"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667939/)? The YouTube algorithm recently served me up a recap video of a story in a series:

The recap does not cover all of what must have been multiple episodes of a plot line.

1. Humans have become extinct.
2. Android robots who know they are robots survive.
3. After 200 years a pair of rebellious android robots create a human female in an artificial womb (revealed at the end of the recap).
4. They later create a male human (at the beginning of the recap)
5. The robotic police who keep androids in line attempt to arrest or take into custody the human male, who shuts down their power supply, escapes the android enclave into the woods where he discovers the female in the basement of a house he comes across.